# Additional field in a many-to-many relationship in gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

There are two model use [gorm](https://gorm.io/) in my project as following:

```golang
type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  Name string `gorm:"type:varchar(128)" json:"name"`
}

type Service struct {
  gorm.Model
  Name string      `gorm:"type:varchar(128)" json:"name"`
  Members []*User  `gorm:"many2many:user_to_service;" json:"members"`
}
```

Now, I need to add a field `role` in the `user_to_service`, represent the user role in the service such as `admin`, `member`, `guest` and so on.

How do I add the `role` field in `user_to_service`? And How to update or query with this field use gorm?

Comment: what is user_to_service?

Comment: user_to_service is a table contains the user_id and service_id @SeniorPomidor